# How To Create Multiple Build Profiles

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop, xamarin.android

We are developing a Game for Windows Phone and want to port it to Android and iOS. Of course we want to keep just a single source base. Having said that I'm wondering whether or not MonoDevelop allows to define multiple build profiles in a single solution, i.e. a build profile for Windows Phone, a build profile for Android, and a build profile for iOS.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks,
j3d

Answer (score 2):

Well, Yes and no.

What you can't do is have a solution MyGame.sln with one project MyGame.csproj and have the build targets like iOS, Android and WP.

But, what you will need to do is:
Create a solution that has many projects: MyGame.Android.csproj, MyGame.iOS.csproj, MyGame.WP.csproj. But before you dispair, you can use the exact same code files - just add them as linked files.

Each platform is not a build target, but rather a separate app. Just as you can't run an Android app on iOS, you can't compile a project for more than one platform. Just as you can't use a normal Class Library with Silverlight, you can't use an Android Library with Windows Phone. But theres nothing stoping you from using the same code files.

So, what you have to do is:

```
-- MyGame.sln
-- -- Game.Android.csproj
-- -- -- CoolFile.cs <--\
-- -- Game.iOS.csproj   |
-- -- -- CoolFile.cs <--| - these are the same files
-- -- Game.WP.csproj    |
-- -- -- CoolFile.cs <--/
```

If your game requires lots of file, it may be easier to split the files into a library:

```
-- MyGame.Android.sln
-- -- Game.Android.csproj
-- -- -- Activity1.cs                    Not shared (different on each platform)
-- -- Game.SharedLibrary.Android.csproj
-- -- -- CoolFile.cs                     Shared code file

-- MyGame.iOS.sln
-- -- Game.iOS.csproj
-- -- -- ViewController1.cs              Not shared (different on each platform)
-- -- Game.SharedLibrary.iOS.csproj
-- -- -- CoolFile.cs                     Shared code file
```

But if you are using MonoGame or such, then you should be able to reuse all the code and just link to the files. So what you would do here is to create one project (and the library projects) for each platform and simply link the files.

Comment: We already have some libraries (e.g. engine, networking, ai, etc.), so we could keep them as compiled with VisualStudio and then just create the additional libraries with non-shared code, right?

Comment: That is correct, but you will have to re-compile for each platform. - I think. That is, Create a Android Class Library projects, an iOS Class Library project file and a WP Class Library project file. You can use the same code files - just link.

Answer (score 1):

Matthew's solution is correct, but I'd like to elaborate a bit on solution and project configurations.

Solution and project build configurations in MonoDevelop work exactly the same way as Visual Studio. A solution can target any mixture of things that its projects can target. However, each of the platforms you are targeting requires a special project type, so a single project cannot target multiple platforms. However, your solution can contain several projects that each target a different platform. It can also contain libraries that contain shared code for these projects.

Suppose you have a solution that contains four projects:

1. SharedLibrary
2. MonoForAndroidProject
3. MonoTouchProject
4. WindowsPhoneProject

Suppose that each of these has the default project configurations for these project types.

Your solution configurations, the things you see in the configuration picker in the toolbar, can be anything you want - the names have no special significance. Each of them can map to any set (or subset) of projects and project configurations.

For example, you could have a four debug configurations:

1. **DebugIPhone**: maps to *Debug|AnyCPU* configuration of *SharedLibrary*, and *Debug|iPhone* configuration of *MonoTouchProject*
2. **DebugIPhoneSimulator**: maps to *Debug|AnyCPU* configuration of *SharedLibrary*, and Debug|iPhoneSimulator configuration of *MonoTouchProject*
3. **DebugAndroid**: maps to *Debug|AnyCPU* configuration of *SharedLibrary*, and *Debug|AnyCPU* configuration of *MonoForAndroidProject*
4. **DebugWinPhone**: maps to *Debug|AnyCPU* configuration of *SharedLibrary*, and *Debug|AnyCPU* configuration of *WindowsPhoneProject*

Another example, you could have a Release configuration that builds all the device packages: *Release|AnyCPU* configuration of *SharedLibrary*, and *Release|iPhone* configuration of *MonoTouchProject*, *Release|AnyCPU* configuration of *MonoForAndroidProject*, *Release|AnyCPU* configuration of *WindowsPhoneProject*.

You could also add target-specific project configurations to the SharedLibrary, with symbols defined to affect #if directives in the source code, and map these from the appropriate solution configurations, though this wouldn't be compatible with having a single configuration to build for all devices.

Right now you would run into a few problems with the above solution.

Firstly, MonoDevelop cannot load and build Windows Phone projects, and Visual Studio cannot load and build MonoTouch projects. So you'd get an error when loading it into either IDE - but the other projects would still work.

Secondly, there isn't a library type that all of the project types can reference. You *might* be able to get away with using e.g. a MfA library project and referencing it as a dll from the other project types. Another possibility would be to have multiple library projects that include the same files - these projects could be in the same directory, and include the same files in-place, or they could be in different locations and include the files as file links. You could use the Visual Studio project linker to keep them in sync.

Some people to prefer to have multiple solution files, one for each platform. You have a lot of flexibility:

- they can include the same projects, or separate projects, or a mixture
- their projects can include (or link) the same files, or different files, or a mixture
- they can be in the same directories, or have separate directories, or a a mixture

Comment: Thank you for your comments. As you say the problem is that MonoDevlop cannot load WP projects and VisualStudio cannot load MonoDroid/MonoTouch projects. Furthermore it is much easier to have a solution for each platform, i.e. there is no need to have dozen of configurations and there are no problems when using different IDEs for the different target platforms. On the other side, having a solution referencing sources of another solution is not that elegant...